# Web usage monitoring

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

We are group of friends working in shared wifi network.

Can anyone of us monitor what other guys are surfing from their computer?

Is there any tools or Admin right for such monitoring?

Comment: First question: yes, second question is off-topic, but check out `nmap`, `wireshark`, ...

Comment: @dawud: if "Yes" then how? using such tools only?

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**

Short answer: Yes.

Large answer: see second question.

**Second question:**

Depends on your experience as a sysadmin but I recommend something simple like view of the DMZ of your router. You can see web usage if you can access to router and go to menu level DMZ if your router have this. Normally you can record all access.

Another question is install any proxy or firewall Between a new router and AP (Access Point).

Your config: ROUTER (wifi enabled)
New config: ROUTER (wifi disabled) + PROXY / FIREWALL + AP

Everything at cheap proxy / firewall I recommend small device, something like Raspberry Pi.

Comment: and if I dont have router access : )

Comment: @KarimkhanPathan If you don't have router access then your questions is completely off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking the question to prevent people monitoring your machine? If so why not use a VPN. OpenVPN would be my recommendation or even the tor browser which is a one click secure browser.

If you want to monitor other peoples traffic than you would be packet sniffing. Wire shark would be my preferred choice for monitoring wifi packets.